# html form - automatic button focus when pressing enter

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, focus

I'm building a table from which I want to update different fields of a database. The current value is output, followed by a submit button and a text field for inputting the new value.

When I input a new value for a certain field, I want the submit button for this text field to get automatically focused, to be able to simply press ENTER to update the database. How is this achieved? I'm thinking it must be possible with simple HTML. Here's a piece of code:

```
echo "
<form method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Amount to receive</th>
            <td>" . mysql_result($result, 0, "amountToReceive") . "</td>" . "
            <td><input type='submit' value='Change' name='btnChangeAmountToReceive'> <input type='text' name='txtChangeAmountToReceive'></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <th>Amount received</th>
            <td>" . mysql_result($result, 0, "amountReceived") . "</td>" . "
            <td><input type='submit' value='Change' name='btnChangeAmountReceived'> <input type='text' name='txtChangeAmountReceived'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>";
```

Comment: I would use javascript to accomplish this - are you looking for a javascript answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to accomplish that is by using javascript, and I'd suggest you using jQuery.

```
    $('#mytextfield').change(function(e) {
        $('input[type=submit]').focus();
    });
```

Or you can try jarry's

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return focusOnEnter(event)" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusOnEnter(e)
{
var keynum = e.keyCode || e.which;  //for compatibility with IE < 9
if(keycode == 13) //13 is the enter char code
    document.getElementsByName('btnChangeAmountReceived')[0].focus();
return true;
}
</script>
```

You can also autofocus an element on HTML5 by adding the attribute `autofocus="autofocus"`

Comment: actually, i think that onchange its better than onkeypress. but i wouldn't use jquery because he said plain html.

Answer (score 2):

as kinakuta said, you have to use some javascript to do what you want.

something like this would do the trick

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return focusOnEnter(event)" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusOnEnter(e)
{
var keynum = e.keyCode || e.which;  //for compatibility with IE < 9
if(keycode == 13) //13 is the enter char code
    document.getElementsByName('btnChangeAmountReceived')[0].focus();
return true;
}
</script>
```

EDIT

after reading Frank S.'s answer,  i think that a better solution it's to use onchange event:

```
<input type="text" onchange="focusOnEnter()" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusOnEnter()
{
    document.getElementsByName('btnChangeAmountReceived')[0].focus();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'tabindex' attribute for input element to accomplish your requirement which is simple html.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kinakuta said, JavaScript(jQuery) would do it much better I think. Here is a link that explains everything you need. http://jqueryminute.com/set-focus-to-the-next-input-field-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusbutton() 
{
  if( event.keyCode == 13 )
  document.getElementById('BUTTON_ID').click();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusbutton() 
{
 if( event.keyCode == 13 )
 document.getElementById('BUTTON_ID').click();
}
</script>
```

13 : ASCII Code Of Enter